# AHK Run command with directory path containing space

Tags: autohotkey

Using AHK script to open up and launch text files (or script files) within notepad++. I recently had to add spaces to my file path which has caused the problems I now experience. It's as if the space in the file path is escaping the command.

e.g.

```
Run % "notepad++.exe C:\C Docs\SW\AHK\Desktop1.ahk"
```

Upon running the above line, it will ask in msgbox: `"C:\C" doesn't exist. Create it?`

This script happens to be the script location itself. So I also tried the following without success (produces same message):

```
Run % "notepad++.exe " . a_scriptdir . "\" . A_ScriptName
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing two arguments to Notepad++ the first one being `C:\C` and the second one being `Docs\SW\AHK\Desktop1.ahk`.
To pass them as one argument, do what you'd always do with command line arguments, quote them.

```
Run, % "notepad++.exe ""C:\C Docs\SW\AHK\Desktop1.ahk"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
Run notepad++.exe "C:\C Docs\SW\AHK\Desktop1.ahk"
```

Comment: Both answers thus far should work. However, @Helpers answer would be the favored one by most programmers for clarity and simplicity. Essentially the quotes as stated in OP will join everything together as a single string as if the spaces didn't exist.